# Active Record serialized attr losing string encodings (probably YAML issue), workarounds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, yaml

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 with Ruby 1.9.1 and I'm having a problem with
serialized attributes in active record not preserving string encodings.
The underlying problem is probably yaml, but I'm wondering if anyone has
any good ideas on how to handle this.  The app I'm working on has
numerous serialized fields some of which contain deep structures of
arrays and hashes. Getting back an ASCII-8Bit string (that's actually
UTF-8) deep within those structures wrecks havoc later...

Perhaps best illustrated by example, if I save l to a serialized attr in
an active record model I'll get back l2 on reading from the database.

```
>> l
=> ["English", "Türkçe", "Русский"]
>> l.map(&:encoding)
=> [#<Encoding:UTF-8>, #<Encoding:UTF-8>, #<Encoding:UTF-8>]
>> l.map(&:valid_encoding?)
=> [true, true, true]
>> l.to_yaml
=> "--- \n- English\n- !binary |\n  VMO8cmvDp2U=\n\n-
\"\\xD0\\xA0\\xD1\\x83\\xD1\\x81\\xD1\\x81\\xD0\\xBA\\xD0\\xB8\\xD0\\xB9\"\n"
>> l2 = YAML.load(l.to_yaml)
=> ["English", "T\xC3\xBCrk\xC3\xA7e", "Русский"]
>> l2.map(&:encoding)
=> [#<Encoding:UTF-8>, #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>, #<Encoding:UTF-8>]
```

Does anyone know how yaml decides on whether or not to store a string as
binary vs. as an escaped string? Both the last two strings above are
non-ascii-7 but only the first is stored as binary...

My current thinking is to hook the active record deserialization routine, walk hashes and arrays and force encoding on all the string elements.  Not terribly safe or general, but would probably work for my use case, though I also wonder if anyone's patched YAML to be smarter here...

Answer (score 1):

I did come up with one solution :

monkey patching String can force YAML to use \ escaping rather then binary and therefore return strings in the default encoding (UTF-8 for me) rather then ASCII-8BIT

```
class String
  def is_binary_data?
    encoding == Encoding::ASCII_8BIT unless empty?
  end
end
```

originally this routine uses some heuristics around which would be shorter \ escaping of binary encoding of the string which is why only some of the international strings I had were having problems.